# HTML & CSS - Why is my navigation bar not showing?

Tags: flexbox, header, navbar

My navbar is not showing on my screen except for the Hero section. I've spent a few hours trying to see if there was a problem and I pretty much copied a template from a project I followed step-by-step on Youtube but I still can't seem to find what the problem is. Is the problem lying in the HTML or CSS?

For the navbar, I tried using the nav element but it didn't seem to work so I created a div with class called "navbar" but it still deson't work.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Blockchain</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Header section-->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="header container">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <!-- 
                                            <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="/images/btc_logo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    -->
                    <div class="nav-list">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#hero" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#speakers" data-after="Home">Speakers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#schedule" data-after="Home">Schedule</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#venue" data-after="Home">Venue</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact" data-after="Home">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#register" class="btn">Register</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header section-->

        <!-- Hero section-->
        <section class="hero section" id="hero">
            <div class="hero container">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h1>Blockchain<span></span></h1>
                    <h1>Technology<span></span></h1>
                    <h1>Conference<span></span></h1>
                    <a href="#" type="button" class="btn">Explore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        -->
        <!-- end Hero section-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
/* General */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Sets the general container to 100% height and aligns things to center */
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* sets images to 100% height & width and to cover space */
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
/* set the properties of all paragraph elements */
p {
    color: rgb(37, 36, 36);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}
/* title for each section */
.section-title {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: goldenrod;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
    text-align: center;
}
/* General */

/* header and navbar  */
#header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}
#header .header {
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}
.header .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}
/* generate background of navbar */
.navbar .nav-list ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(37, 36, 36);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s ease left;
}
.navbar .nav-list ul.active {
    left: 0%;
}
/* the nav links */
.navbar .nav-list ul a {
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}
/* end header and navbar  */
.navbar .nav-list ul a::after {
    content: attr(data-after);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    color: rgb(37, 36, 36, 0.021);
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 44px;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 3.5s ease letter-spacing;
}

/* Hero section */
#hero {
    background-image: url(/images/conference.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* end Hero section */
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for the `.navbar .nav-list ul` rule you have `left: 100%;`, which completely pushes the `navbar` outside the viewport. If you change `left` to be smaller, then you will see it at the right-hand side of the screen. You can correspondingly decrease `width` as well.

```css
/* General */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Sets the general container to 100% height and aligns things to center */
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* sets images to 100% height & width and to cover space */
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
/* set the properties of all paragraph elements */
p {
    color: rgb(37, 36, 36);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}
/* title for each section */
.section-title {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: goldenrod;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
    text-align: center;
}
/* General */

/* header and navbar  */
#header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}
#header .header {
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}
.header .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
}
/* generate background of navbar */
.navbar .nav-list ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(37, 36, 36);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s ease left;
}
.navbar .nav-list ul.active {
    left: 0%;
}
/* the nav links */
.navbar .nav-list ul a {
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}
/* end header and navbar  */
.navbar .nav-list ul a::after {
    content: attr(data-after);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    color: rgb(37, 36, 36, 0.021);
    font-size: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 44px;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 3.5s ease letter-spacing;
}

/* Hero section */
#hero {
    background-image: url(/images/conference.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* end Hero section */

.navbar .nav-list ul {
    left: 65%;
    width: 35vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Blockchain</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Header section-->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="header container">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <!-- 
                                            <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="/images/btc_logo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    -->
                    <div class="nav-list">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#hero" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#speakers" data-after="Home">Speakers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#schedule" data-after="Home">Schedule</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#venue" data-after="Home">Venue</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact" data-after="Home">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#register" class="btn">Register</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header section-->

        <!-- Hero section-->
        <section class="hero section" id="hero">
            <div class="hero container">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <h1>Blockchain<span></span></h1>
                    <h1>Technology<span></span></h1>
                    <h1>Conference<span></span></h1>
                    <a href="#" type="button" class="btn">Explore</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        -->
        <!-- end Hero section-->
    </body>
</html>
```